# How do I save a search query and display it on a new component?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have created a new page called saved search. Using the save button I want to be able to send the entered dates to be displayed on the new page. So they are displayed there once I click the button.

What I have done so far?
I am able to enter date ranges and when I click the save button I able to see them logged onto the console.

What I am looking for?
I want to display dates saved and logged to the console on the new page. What is the process for doing that? I want to be able to display the logged console data onto the new page.

Video example would be useful if anyone can redirect me to them, if not a written resolution would do just fine.

New Search Screen is used to create a search here I can create a search using date range picker to see the list according to date of birth and date received:
[image: New Search Screen is used to create a search here I can create a search using date range picker to see the list according to date of birth and date received]

[image: Saved Search Screen I would like to display search entries which were saved in new search and are displayed in the console]

1st image = Saved Search Screen I would like to display search entries that were saved from the new search and are displayed in the console.

Queries logged from the new search screen to the console:

```html
fromDateReceived: Wed Apr 01 2020 13:24:24 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) {}
toDateReceived: Sun Apr 05 2020 13:24:24 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) {}
fromDateOfBirth: Mon Apr 06 2020 13:24:24 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) {}
toDateOfBirth: Wed Apr 08 2020 13:24:24 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) {}
```

Currently using onSubmit to capture the queries in the searchcomponent.ts:

```js
onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.searchForm.value);
    this.savedsearchService.savedsearch(this.searchForm.value)
    .subscribe(
      response => console.log('Successful', response),
      error => console.error('Error', error)
    );
  }
```

The following the saved.service.ts:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SavedSearchService {

  url = 'http://localhost:4200/ui/savedSearch';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  savedsearch(searchData) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.url, searchData);
  }
}
```

Comment: u can take input from another components u can search https://angular.io/api/core/Input, OR u can use sessionStorage method also

Comment: Are you posting your data here `http://localhost:4200/ui/savedSearch` ??? Do you have a rest endpoint there?

Comment: I don't have an API or DB set up for it. @robert

Comment: @robert apologies if I am unclear this is the first time I am working on something like this.

Comment: @Çağrı - I want to store the data locally for the moment.

Comment: then on `onSubmit()` you can do simple `localStorage.setItem('savedDates', JSON.stringify(this.searchForm.value));` on the other side when you want to use do the opposite `const retrievedDates = localStorage.getItem('savedDates');` basically what @Danil wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can store your dates in local storage.
The second, its create a Subject in SavedSearchService.

there a little example on stackblitz(not mine): [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviorsubject-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)